# Can't select HTML element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, child-nodes

```
     <body>
    <table id="table_x">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>                         
                <td>this box should be selected</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
```

With the following javascript code, I want to select the second "box" in the first row of the table with the id "table_x":

```
        var matrix = document.querySelector("#table_x");
        var row;
        var box;

        function select(x,y){
            row = matrix.childNodes[x];
            box = row.childNodes[y];
            return box;
        }

        var test = select(0,1);
```

However, when I want to output the element in the console (using the command console.log(test);) I just get back "undefined". What's wrong with my selection of the html element?

Comment: Re your edit: There is no element in your quoted HTML with `id="matrix"`, so `document.querySelector("#matrix")` will return `null`.

Comment: sorry, when posting here I changed the original ids a bit but forgot to do it consistently ... I've updated the code now ...

Comment: the thing is that also in the case of correct ids my code doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're trying to get row `x`, and then get cell `y` from it. (I'd've used `y` for rows and `x` for cells, but your code appears to be doing the opposite.)

If so, you don't want to use `childNodes` because that includes not only elements, but also comment nodes, text nodes, etc.

Separately, you'll want to make sure that `matrix` refers to the `tbody` element, not the `table` element..

Then you can use any of these; note that one of them doesn't even need the `matrix` variable:

```
function select1(x, y) {
  return matrix.children[x].children[y];
}

function select2(x, y) {
  return matrix.rows[x].cells[y];
}

function select3(x, y) {
  var selector = "#table_x tr:nth-child(" + (x + 1) + ") > td:nth-child(" + (y + 1) + ")";
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

Example of all three:

```js
var matrix = document.querySelector("#table_x tbody");

function select1(x, y) {
  return matrix.children[x].children[y];
}

function select2(x, y) {
  return matrix.rows[x].cells[y];
}

function select3(x, y) {
  var selector = "#table_x tr:nth-child(" + (x + 1) + ") > td:nth-child(" + (y + 1) + ")";
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

select1(0, 0).style.color = "blue";
select2(1, 1).style.color = "green";
select3(2, 2).style.color = "red";
```

```html
<table id="table_x">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! Option 3, let CSS find it for you, no need to write your own traversal code, though I must admit the traversal with rows and cells is pretty simple

Comment: so `rows` and `cells` methods can be called by table Node or tbody Node ???

Comment: @Mahi: Yes, both [`HTMLTableElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#htmltableelement) and [`HTMLTableSectionElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#htmltablesectionelement) have `rows`. Naturally, the `HTMLTableSectionElement` will only have the rows that it, specifically, contains; the `HTMLTableElement` will have all of the ones in the table: https://jsfiddle.net/bv1en1g6/

Comment: "I'd have used y for rows and x for cells". I'll never forget the handy mnemonic given to me by my maths teacher years ago, to help me remember which way `x` and `y` are oriented on a graph. "x is across.".

Comment: @JasonEvans: Wow, how did I never hear that? That's brilliant!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah when he said that to me, with the reference to "across" and "a cross", it was one of those major "aha!" moments during my school days lol.

Answer (score 2):

While selecting something in a html table you can take advantage of the special `rows` property of the table and the similar `cells` property of each row,

here's an updated version of your function (added the `id` parameter):

```js
   function select(x, y, id) {
     var matrix = document.getElementById(id)
     var row = matrix.rows[x];
     var box = row.cells[y];
     return box;
   }

   var test = select(0, 1, 'table_x').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<table id="table_x">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>this box should be selected</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements can contain both element nodes *and* text nodes.

The first child node of `table_x` is a whitespace text node – *not* the TBODY element.

To skip text nodes and work with element nodes only, use [**`children`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead of `childNodes`.

```
function select(x, y) {
  row = matrix.children[x];
  box = row.children[y];
  return box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `childNodes`use `rows` and `cells` specific for tables. Also you can make the function smaller/faster merging the `row` and `box` variables into the return.

```js
var matrix = document.getElementById("table_x");

function select(x,y){
  return matrix.rows[x].cells[y];
}

var test = select(0,1);
console.log(test);
```

```html
<body>
    <table id="table_x">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>                         
                <td>this box should be selected</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
```